# How execute cat filename* in python

Tags: python, process, wildcard, cat

I'm really new to python and after several hours of looking I haven't been able to find a solution (or failed to understand the solutions provided by other people).

I wanted to check the contents of several files with the same initial name 'pid' followed by a non-consecutive integer in a folder to make sure they all contained the word 'done'. The files contain a single word.

My initial idea was to use

```
cat pid*
```

somehow get the outputs of that command into a list and then just transverse the list comparing the values

```
result = 'Finished'
for x in range(len(myList)):
    if 'done' not in myList[x]:
        result = 'Continue'
        break
if result == 'Finished':
    print 'Finished'
```

that was my idea, but I can't find the way of getting that list containing the output of cat.

After some digging around I gave up on the idea and made a really POOR implementation (I think) I'm sure there has to be a better solution

```
filedir = os.popen('ls','r')

for line in filedir:
    print line
    if 'pid' in line:
        filename = open(line.replace('\n', ''), 'r')
        firstline = filename.readline()
        print firstline
        if 'done' not in firstline:
            status = 'RUNNING'
            break
if status == 'DONE':
    print 'Finished'
else:
    print status
```

Any help is really appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`glob`](http://docs.python.org/library/glob.html) module, which "finds all the pathnames matching a specified pattern according to the rules used by the Unix shell":

```
import glob
for fn in glob.glob('pid*'):
    with open(fn) as f:
        if 'done' in f.read():
            ...
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, I wasn't aware of this glob class, far a head in the python tutorial I'm reading. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Use [`glob`](http://docs.python.org/library/glob.html) to perform the wildcard match and then read the files.

And please... **stop calling shell commands for things that can be easily done in python itself**

Comment: The `glob` module is preferred when dealing with paths, since `fnmatch` doesn't treat slashes separately.  Though I do like your note. ;)

Comment: I wasn't aware of the glob class, I found that shell command before I got to the glob. I'm still new to this but, slow and steady =]. Thanks for the reply.